# Django form not submitting data to database

Tags: python, django

I've dig through old post about this topic but like allways nothing works for me. My problem is that data isn't saved. I've printed out form and it's okey, then I've **printed out forms.is_valid which gave me true**, forms.save() also returns customer object so I don't know where to look now
(this form updates user shipping data)

**form**

```py
class customerUpdate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = ShippingAddress
        fields  = ['city', 'country','zip_code','adress','phone',]
        exclude = ['customer','order','date_added']
        widgets ={
          'city'      :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'updateForm',}),
          'country'   :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'updateForm',}),
          'zip_code'  :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'updateForm',}),
          'adress'    :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'updateForm',}),
          'phone'     :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'updateForm',}),
       }
```

**Model**

```py
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer    = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order       = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    city        = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    country     = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code    = models.TextField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    phone       = models.TextField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)
    adress      = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.adress)
```

**views**

```py
def userView(request):
    userData = request.user.customer
    forms = customerUpdate(instance=userData)
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms = customerUpdate(request.POST, instance=userData)
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save()
    
    context={
        'userData':userData,
        'forms':forms
    }    return render(request,'user.html', context)
```

**html**

```html
{% load i18n  %}
<div class="editUserInfoWrapper">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'user'  %}"class="formUserPanel" >
        {% csrf_token  %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ forms.city  }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ forms.country  }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ forms.zip_code  }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ forms.adress  }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-3">
               
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ forms.phone  }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-3">
               
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btnSbtRegister">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go down the list. In your views, have you tried `userData = request.user` instead of `userData = request.user.customer`?

Also, you can try

```
if request.method = 'post':
    form = customerUpdate(request.data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.customer = request.user
        form.save()
....
```